# Can I use micropython in NodeMcu ?(model name: CH340 Lua WIFI)

Tags: esp8266, micropython

I’am about to buy NodeMcu v3 CH340 Lua Wifi model.
So I just wonder this model is only using Lua language..
I want using micropython on this model.
So Is it OK?

Comment: Since You try to start developing Python for the NodeMcu You may have a look at this tutorial/documentation I've recently set up: [python2nodemcu](https://github.com/pixelstuermer/python2nodemcu). It tries to cover the whole process in a very easy and understandable language without too many technical depts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of whichever firmware comes pre-installed on the ESP8266 dev board ([comparison](https://frightanic.com/iot/comparison-of-esp8266-nodemcu-development-boards/)) you can always replace it with whatever else you like.

See this for installing MicroPython: http://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/esp8266/tutorial/intro.html#intro. Sorry, I cannot copy-paste the whole article but if the link ever becomes outdated search for "Getting started with MicroPython on the ESP8266".

Comment: Oh... this is my first question on stackoverflow. And really reall appreciate your reply and answer!! Thanks a lot : )

Comment: Glad to help. If you like this answer and if you think it answers your question then please upvote and/or [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/257994). SO could then mark it as answered/closed.

Comment: May I ask one more?? :)